# Migrating mysql 'users' to new machine gives off errors

Tags: mysql, user-management, permissions, navicat

I have looked at the settings a great number of times but run into the same issue. When connected to my Linux box with the 'exact' same settings, no fault. When run on a fresh machine with xampp for testing:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied
>   for user 'user'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

I'm positive the user name, privileges and password are the same so anything else I could be missing?

Comment: The user is `@'localhost'` on both computers?

Comment: the user is technically defined as user@% so yes - I also have the same setup running on another windows machine and it works. Just so happens to occur on a fresh laptop install

Comment: @DerfK - note, when I specifically state host as "localhost" in my mysql (I use navicat) configuration, it works, when I use the wildcard % it does not (even though the error above clearly shows it is trying to connect to the localhost hostname

Comment: and this only works on one of the databases, not the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have skip-name-resolve option turned on.